# How find the function $f(x)$ such $\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\cos{(nx)}dx=0$

Tags: integration, analysis

> let $f(x)$ is Continuous function on $[0,\pi]$,and for  infinite positive integer $n$ such
>   $$\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\cos{(nx)}dx=0$$
>   Find the $f(x)$?

I think the answer is $f(x)=c$?,But maybe have other function,Thank you

My problem is for infinite postive integer $n$,not for any positive integer.

Comment: Any constant function $f(x) = c$ is ok since 
$$\int_{0}^\pi \cos(nx)dx  = \frac{1}{n}[\sin(nx)]_0^\pi = 0$$

Answer (score 2):

Building on Surb's answer, any function that can be written as a sum of the form (with $M$ possibly infinite): $$\sum_{m=0}^M a_m \sin{((n+2m)x)}$$ will satisfy $\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\cos{(nx)}dx=0$.

In addition, for $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $m\neq n$, $\int_0^\pi \cos{(mx)}\cos{(nx)}=0$.

So more generally, $$f(x)=c+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(a_m \sin((n+2m)x)+b_m\cos(mx)\right)$$ where $a_m,b_m,c$ are all constants and $b_n=0$, is a solution.

Comment: well done, actually this looks a lot like a Fourrier series.

Comment: It's related to a Fourier series. It just has slightly different basis functions (mainly $\sin((n+2m)x)$ instead of $\sin(mx)$)

Comment: yes that is what I noticed too.

Comment: No,my problem is for infinite postive integer not for any postive integer.

Comment: @chinamath what do you mean with "for infinite positive integer" ?

Answer (score 1):

Another example: Let  $k \in \mathbb{N}$ [then](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20sin%28k%20x%29%20cos%28n%20x%29%20dx%200%20%3C%20x%20%3C%20pi)

$$\int_{0}^\pi \sin(kx)\cos(nx)dx  =\frac{-n\sin(\pi k)\sin(\pi n)+k(1-\cos(\pi k)\cos(\pi n))}{k^2+n^2}. $$
So for every $k = n + 2m, m \in \mathbb{N}$ this integral is zero.